# postgresql, get result table as json object

Tags: postgresql

given this query:

```
select distinct(column), count(*) from table group by column;
```

that returns these results:

```
column|count
------|-----
id1   |1
id2   |5
...
```

i would like to obtain the results as json with this structure:

```
{ 
  "id1":1,
  "id2":5
}
```

what postgresql json functions should i look?
i tried

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
from(
select  distinct(column), count(*) from table group by column
) t
```

but i have as result an array of objects

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b` And using `distinct` together with `group by` is also useless

Answer (score 0):

answer:

```
WITH l AS (select distinct(column), count(*) from table group by column)
SELECT json_agg(json_build_object(column, count)) FROM l
```